# browser back acts on nested iframe before the page itself - is there a way to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe, back-button

I have a page with dynamic data loaded by some ajax and lots of javascript.

the page contains a list from which the user can choose and each selected value loads new data to the page.

One of these data items is a url provided to an iframe.

I use [jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) to simulate the browser-back behavior.

All works well besides the fact that when i click the back button for the first time the iframe goes back to its previous location and then I need to click back again to make the page go back.

Is there a way to disable the iframe's back behavior?

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this; my understanding (possibly incorrect) is that the page has little or no control over what the browser does with the "back" button. Or the "forward" button for that matter.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I've found the answer to my problem guess it could be useful for others out there.

The problem was with the way i assigned new URLs to my Iframe, i used Jquery so it looked something like that:

```
$('#myIFrame').attr('src',newUrl);
```

When assigning the URL in that manner it adds a new entry to the browser's list of visited URLs to go back to.
That wasn't the desired behavior, so after some googling i found that you can assign a new URL  to an Iframe object without adding it to the 'back-list', it looks like that:

```
var frame = $('#myIFrame')[0];  
frame.contentWindow.location.replace(newUrl);
```

This way my back button behave exactly as expected.

btw, i got my answer from [here](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/ignoring-iframes-with-javascript-history-t67189.html).

Hope this was helpful to you as it was to me.

Comment: This only works for iframe with the same domain as the website it is embedded on. Will not work for cross-domain iframes.

Comment: How can i use this code when i submit form with target="myIFrame" to point to iframe??

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer does not seem to work if you try to set a cross-domain URL for the IFrame. As a workaround, I detached the IFrame from the DOM before setting the `src` (using jQuery).

```
// remove IFrame from DOM before setting source, 
// to prevent adding entries to browser history
var newUrl = 'http://www.example.com';
var iFrame = $('#myIFrame');
var iFrameParent = iFrame.parent();

iFrame.remove();
iFrame.attr('src', newUrl);
iFrameParent.append(iFrame);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a hyperlink within your iframe. call it 'Back' and put a href as javascript:history.back(-1)That's the best you can do I think.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to prevent the addition of new history entries in the iframe, [history.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState()_method) introduced in HTML5 would work in most cases.

```
history.pushState(state, title, url);
```

Comment: Inside the iframe? How do I tell the iframe to do that if `src="http:/google.com"` for example?

Answer (score 0):

I manage cross domain iframe inside bootstrap modal, the only solution working for me is to put the following code inside the head of the each iframe pages:

```
    history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
    window.onpopstate = function () {
      history.go(1);
    };
```

This will not work for everyone as you need to have the control of the iframe content, in addition it break the history chain of the parent window

Answer (score -5):

No, this is entirely up to the browser.