# How to get back button work on parent page instead in iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I have two iframe in my index.php as bellow.

```html
                    <iframe src="compare/search.php" scrolling="no" name="ifrm"></iframe>
                    <iframe src="compare/search.php" scrolling="no" name="ifrm"></iframe>
```

In these iframes search.php are loaded.. which search the product from mySql database and display's the details in same iframe..like bellow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xx2W.jpg)
and get the details like these:-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2XgP.jpg)

the problem is whenever i get details and try's to go to the previous page by pressing back button instead of reaching to previous page the iframe get backed. and after 3 times of pressing back button the parent page get back ...

i hope someone will help me
thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [browser back acts on nested iframe before the page itself - is there a way to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245883/browser-back-acts-on-nested-iframe-before-the-page-itself-is-there-a-way-to-av)

Answer (score 0):

Thats cause with the iframes the window gets new entries in the visit sites list.
If you want to redirect to a specific page, I reccommend to add it with a script.

Comment: i dont want to redirect to a specific page..i want to stop iframe to add new entries in the visit sites list..is that possibal? plzz help