# Cannot use contentWindow.location.replace(...) how can I work around this?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsx

So my initial issue is that whenever I click on a webpage (which loads an iFrame page within the page) and I interact with the iFrame, I have to click the back button multiple times in order to actually go back to the previous page I was on. I have found similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245883/browser-back-acts-on-nested-iframe-before-the-page-itself-is-there-a-way-to-av) which is pretty much what Im attempting, but I cannot use `contentWindow.location.replace` because of CORS/security restrictions.

**What is an alternative to work around the CORs/security restrictions? I just need help using something else than contentWindow or can I use contentWindow somehow? to be able to not have more history added to the queue so the back button is only needed to be hit once instead of 2-3 times right now.**

I am using

```
$('#myIFrame').setAttribute('src', `newUrl`);
```

in my code. So I figured that could be my solution, just cant figure out the contentWindow part. As I think the fix is the link I provided above. [browser back acts on nested iframe before the page itself - is there a way to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245883/browser-back-acts-on-nested-iframe-before-the-page-itself-is-there-a-way-to-av)

I have tried using the method up above but when I run it locally it gives me this error:`Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contentWindow')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated it with some more clarity.

Comment: Have you explord the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)? Also, you can maybe have a go at saving the last visited page and add an event listener for a custom 'back' action? I have some suspicion that if the back button page is executed on the parent page, then you would actually go back; if that's not the case (really not sure!), then it means that your iframe is interacting with the session History, so you can just use that.

Comment: Ill take a look at that for sure!